# ArcGIS Online Edit Webmap Layer URL

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online

I have a saved webmap containing layers pointing at an ArcGIS Server which is now switched off. I need to update webmap, changing the layer URLs to a new ArcGIS Server URL. Layers were added straight to the map using Add Layer From Web. I need the old webmap so I retain styling and popup configuration. My web map ID is also referenced in a JS app. Apparently I can edit the URLs for layers and apps, but not maps. Why? Anyone know a way to edit the layer URLs?

From esri help:
https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/item-details.htm

"URL (Apps and ArcGIS Server layers only)—Changing the URL of an ArcGIS Server layer is only recommended when you move the service to a different server. If you've changed the service—for example, added or removed layers—you should add the service as a new item. Any map that uses the moved layer will appear broken because it references the old URL. To fix the map, delete the layer, add it again with the new URL reference, and save the map. Any layer properties you saved to the item are still available. If you edit the URL of a changed service, the map may not display correctly, even after you readd the layer. You cannot edit the URL of a hosted feature or tile layer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the ArcGIS Online Assistant - it allows you to modify the URLs for services in web maps  https://ago-assistant.esri.com/

Select "I want to update the URL" from the top menu.

Comment: we don't want link only answers. Please edit the answer and provide information on why this is the answer and more on how to implement.

Comment: Welcome to the site Andreea.  As Brad indicated, link-only answers are discouraged--please add more details to make this an excellent stand-alone answer.  More details on link only answers available here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: +1 for you Andreea because it's not really just a "link" answer. Those that criticized this haven't used this tool before. It's a skeleton of a tool that does aout 3 operations and there are only a couple buttons. You provided instructions as well.